# Disabling Autoformat in Openoffice

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to enter the number 3.10 into a field in Openoffice Calc. Unfortunately, the default setting is to be "smart" and reformat my input as 3.1. Since my column represents section headers, 3.10!=3.1. Also, my document is a CSV file, so I can't reformat the cell as a "-1234.12". How do I disable Calc's autoformating features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cell in the csv file is quoted, e.g. "3.10" and the csv text import box "Quoted field as text" is checked, then the imported value is 3.10 as a text entry.

You can format the header cell as text, then edit it to be 3.10. It will then be exported in the csv file as "3.10" and will import correctly.

If you need the value as a number elsewhere in the spreadsheet, then you can get it using the value() function.

Comment: Doesn't really work, but the best answer so far...